# URI formats are not supported for properties height and width of image

Tags: c#

I am trying to access height and width of an `System.Drawing.Image`.

```
Image image = Image.FromFile(PostedImage.ImageUrl.ToString());
int ActualWidth = image.Width;
int ActualHeight = image.Height;
```

I am getting error

> URI formats are not supported.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass a path to a local file or one on a network drive.

If the string you give it is to a web resources, you have to first download it.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you cannot sent a URL to [`Image.FromFile()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.fromfile.aspx) You must pass a local path on disk.

To remedy this:

- saving your image to a location on disk
- load your image into a Stream of some kind, and use [`Image.FromStream()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/93z9ee4x.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

my guess is that FromFile works on local files only. i would fetch the file using WebRequest and then create Image from stream.